# Calculating variances within a column

Tags: sql, subtraction

[image: Current Data]

[image: Desired result]

Note: 1st table is the current dataset, 2nd table is the requested result.

I was thinking of creating temporary table X and Y which has sales and Sales&Service values data respectively and calculate the variance using a join. I was wondering if that's the right/convenient way to solve this?

Comment: What is your question? Which database you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select region,
       sum(case when type = 'Sales' then - Amount
                when type = 'Sales&Service' then Amount
           end) as service_only
from t
group by region;
```

If you want an overall total, then that depends on your database.  Many support `rollup` or `grouping sets` which allows this as part of the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table product;
create table product(region varchar2(10),type varchar2(30),amount number(5,2));
insert into product values('A','Sales',100);
insert into product values('B','Sales',150);
insert into product values('C','Sales',170);
insert into product values('D','Sales',180);
insert into product values('A',(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),120);
insert into product values('B',(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),195);
insert into product values('C',(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),178.5);
insert into product values('D',(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),183.6);



select sum(decode(type,'Sales',amount,0)) sales,
sum(decode(type,(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),amount,0)) sales_servie_only,
sum(decode(type,(select 'Sales'||'&'||'service' from dual),amount,0))-sum(decode(type,'Sales',amount,0))as total
from product
group by ROLLUP(region);
```

--we can do by using case and decode and sum and group by clause